# How to get the bindingNavigator current page

Tags: c#

I'm talking about this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q5J3LEK.png]

I somehow need to get the database information for that row.

My program alllows searching, so I'm not sure how it works. But what I need is, to get the primary key(id) from the active row being viewed in the bindingNavigator window, then from that id, run a query to get some data from another table that has the same foreign key as the primary key.

So there's going to be one navigation box to the left to navigate through the rows in the database, then each time you change the active row, 3 textboxes to the right will get the related data from the other table (connected with foreign key to the primary key in table 1).

I've tried a while, this for example:

```
 MessageBox.Show(bindingNavigatorPnositionItem.GetCharIndexFromPosition);
```

I realise this isn't going to work, I'm not sure what I'm doing really, since this won't help at all if someone is searching, since it's not the primary key. I could read the data in the "id" field that is displayed when a user changes a page - but how do I check if a user changes a page?

Comment: Your image link doesn't show much of what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: It's a table with "Details" enabled, that I dragged and dropped from Data Sources. It says like 1 of 100 if there's 100 rows.

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly, but the current item for your binding source can be obtained via `bindingNavigator.BindingSource.Current`...

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve but if you want to get the ID or the `Primary Key` of the current record viewed and that it is updated every time there is a change of position, then you could probably do like this:

In your `Form_Load` you could initialize the `PositionChanged` `EventHandler` :

```
 this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(BindingSource_PositionChanged);
```

Then the Event Handler will get the current column or `Primary Key` that you want. Let's just say your primary key is `CustomerID`:

```
 void BindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataRowView currRow = (DataRowView)bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.Current;
     // You could use currRow["CustomerID"].ToString() value below to filter now the related table that has the Foreign Key
     MessageBox.Show(currRow["CustomerID"].ToString()); 
 }
```